# How does re-keying work in Kafka Streams?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform

Noob question, but what is happening when you re-key a topic in Kafka Streams?

For example, let's say I want to implement WordCount, similar to https://docs.confluent.io/4.1.1/streams/quickstart.html, there's a step where you would key the topic by word, and reduce by count.

If the source topic had 10 partitions & there are 10 instances in a Kafka cluster, will the final word count be 1/10 of the actual counts, or will it have the correct count? If it's the latter, how does that happen exactly?

In the use-case I'm thinking of, I have an unkeyed topic that I want to do stateful processing on, but I'm not sure if groupByKey or something can magically make that happen.

Thanks!

Comment: Based on your answer below, it sounds like this solves your problem. If so, this question should be closed as a duplicate. [How Kafka streams handle distributed data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56043681/how-kafka-streams-handle-distributed-data)

Comment: No, his question is different, he is asking about aggregation over multi-partitioned input topic. The one discussed is when input is a single topic. So his question is valid and not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve this with a non-key topic. It will surely generate random result, or there is some concept of global state store which can be used to share state across instances in same same consumer group.

Comment: Thanks @valath. Can you clarify what is the difference between unkeyed & keyed topics in this regard?

For example, sticking with WordCount, suppose that message1 was (123, "hello world") and message 2 was (321, "world hello"). if 123 is partitioned to instance 0 & 321 is partitioned to instance 1, would you still be unable to group word-counts across instances?

Comment: correct, you are correct.